# How to make a draggable UIView snap to the corners over the screen?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uiview

I have a draggable UIView and I am trying to make it snap to four corners of the screen. I tried a few things, but none of them have worked. Here's the code that I have:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import Vision

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var crystalName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var crystalInfoContainer: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var accuracy: UILabel!
    
    var model = IdenticrystClassification().model
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      
        // This method starts the camera.
       let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        
        guard let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }
        guard let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice) else { return }
        captureSession.addInput(input)
        
        captureSession.startRunning()
        
        let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        previewLayer.frame = view.frame
        
        
        // This method defines sub view and defines it's properties.
        view.addSubview(crystalInfoContainer)
        crystalInfoContainer.clipsToBounds = true
        crystalInfoContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        //crystalInfoContainer.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
        
      
        // This method defines torch functionality.
        func toggleTorch(on: Bool) {
            guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }
            
            if device.hasTorch {
                do {
                    try device.lockForConfiguration()
                    
                    if on == true {
                        device.torchMode = .on
                    } else {
                        device.torchMode = .off
                    }
                    
                    device.unlockForConfiguration()
                } catch {
                    print("Torch could not be used")
                }
                } else {
                    print("Torch is not available")
                }
            }
        
        // This is the code that I am trying to work out.
      func relativeVelocity(forVelocity velocity: CGFloat, from currentValue: CGFloat, to targetValue:  CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
            guard currentValue - targetValue != 0 else { return 0 }
            return velocity / (targetValue - currentValue)
        }
        
        func nearestCorner(to point: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
            var minDistance = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
            var closestPosition = CGPoint.zero
            for position in crystalInfoContainer { **Error1**
                let distance = point.distance(to: position)
                if distance < minDistance {
                    closestPosition = position
                    minDistance = distance
                }
            }
            return closestPosition
        
        
        let decelerationRate = UIScrollView.DecelerationRate.normal.rawValue
        let velocity = UIPanGestureRecognizer.velocity(in: view)**Error2**
        let projectedPosition = CGPoint(
            x: crystalInfoContainer.center.x + project(initialVelocity: velocity.x, decelerationRate: decelerationRate),
            y: crystalInfoContainer.center.y + project(initialVelocity: velocity.y, decelerationRate: decelerationRate)
        )
       
        let nearestCornerPosition = nearestCorner(to: projectedPosition)
        
        let relativeInitialVelocity = CGVector(
            dx: relativeVelocity(forVelocity: velocity.x, from: crystalInfoContainer.center.x, to: nearestCornerPosition.x),
            dy: relativeVelocity(forVelocity: velocity.y, from: crystalInfoContainer.center.y, to: nearestCornerPosition.y)
        )
        
        let params = UISpringTimingParameters(damping: 1, response: 0.4, initialVelocity: relativeInitialVelocity)
        let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0, timingParameters: params)
        animator.addAnimations {
            self.crystalInfoContainer.center = nearestCornerPosition
        }
        animator.startAnimation()
        
        }

        let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
                dataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "video"))
                captureSession.addOutput(dataOutput)
        toggleTorch(on: true)
        
    }

    // Handles Visiout output.
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        
        guard let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }
        
        guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: model) else { return }
        let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model)
        { (finishedReq, err) in
            
         guard let results = finishedReq.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] else { return }
         guard let firstObservation = results.first else { return }
            let name: String = firstObservation.identifier
            let acc: Int = Int(firstObservation.confidence * 100)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.crystalName.text = name
                self.accuracy.text = "Confidence: \(acc)%"
                
            }
        }
    
        try? VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, options: [:]).perform([request])

    }
    
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

**Error1:** For-in loop requires 'UIView?' to conform to 'Sequence'; did you mean to unwrap optional?

**Error2:** Instance member 'velocity' cannot be used on type 'UIPanGestureRecognizer'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Comment: There is a good article here: https://medium.com/@nathangitter/building-fluid-interfaces-ios-swift-9732bb934bf5 ... scroll down to the heading `Interface #7: FaceTime PiP` - you may find it shows how to do exactly what you're asking (and does so in a nice, fluid manner).

Comment: @DonMag that article was definitely a help, but it seems that there is some error in my code. I edited the original question to reflect the changes I was able to do based on that article.

Comment: You need to post your complete code (see [mre]). No way to know from the little bits.

Comment: @DonMag Got it. I edited the original post with the code. Thank you!

Comment: Well, that's still just snippets of code... You say you get an error at `for position in crystalInfoContainer` --- What **is** `crystalInfoContainer`? For your second error, related to `velocity`, where do you have that code? Post the code for the full class so we aren't guessing.

Comment: @DonMag got it, edited.

Comment: The code you posted shows `crystalInfoContainer` is a `UIView`, and then you're trying to do a `for` loop on that view? Then, you are trying to use the `.velocity` property of a Pan Gesture, but your code doesn't reference any gestures.

Comment: Go back to that article I linked to. Re-read it. Scroll down to the bottom and get the Demo App code from the GitHub link. Run the demo app, and see it in action. Then study the code and compare it to yours to see what you're doing wrong. You should then be able to implement it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your panView method is wrong. You need to switch on the gesture recognizer’s state — began, changed, or ended.  Pan only when the gesture changes. When the gesture ends, then and only then, animate the view into the nearest corner.